# SQL Server 2012 running total by date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that contains column [Month/Year], [Date], [Volume]

When i run this query "**select [Month/Year], [date], sum([Volume]) as 'sum' from VOLUME where [Month/Year] = '2018-10-01' group by [Month/Year], [date] order by [date]**", it will show this:

```
    [Month/Year]   [Date]   [Volume]
    2018-10-01  2018-10-15  2000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-16  4000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-17  7000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-18  6000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-19  7000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-20  7000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-21  8000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-22  9000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-23  11000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-24  10000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-25  13000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-26  12000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-27  8000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-28  8000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-29  9000
    2018-10-01  2018-10-30  8000
```

When i run this query, it give me this output which is wrong:

```
select a.[date], SUM(b.[Volume]) as barge_sum
from VOLUME a
INNER JOIN VOLUME b ON a.[date] >= b.[date]
where a.[Month/Year] = '2018-10-01'
group by a.[date]
order by a.[date]
```

Output:

```
2018-10-15  4000
2018-10-16  24000
2018-10-17  91000
2018-10-18  114000
2018-10-19  182000
2018-10-20  231000
2018-10-21  328000
2018-10-22  450000
2018-10-23  671000
2018-10-24  710000
2018-10-25  1092000
2018-10-26  1152000
2018-10-27  832000
2018-10-28  896000
2018-10-29  1089000
2018-10-30  1032000
```

The output should be cumulative in this manner:

[image]

What am i doing wrong? Can anyone assist?

Comment: you missed the JOIN condition `a.[Month/Year] = b.[Month/Year]`

Comment: @Squirrel what do you mean? I don't get it

Comment: `ON a.[Month/Year] = b.[Month/Year] AND a.[date] >= b.[date]`

Comment: not working at all

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below by using window function `sum()`

```
select a.[date], SUM(a.[Volume]) over(order by  a.[date]) as barge_sum
from VOLUME a
where a.[Month/Year] = '2018-10-01'
```

Comment: I'm getting this error 'Incorrect syntax near 'order'.'

Comment: @Honestman https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=00b545eaf403fc12282d623ad69960b5 check this fiddle

Comment: OP is using `SQL Server 2012`

Comment: @Squirrel https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=00b545eaf403fc12282d623ad69960b5 check sql server 2012

Comment: my apology . . i must have got the version mix-up in my head

Comment: @Squirrel its ok mate

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Thanks but how do i apply ur query to my?

Comment: @Honestman i already did for your one in my answer